# algorithms to select price ranges

Tags: e-commerce

What is best way to represent a sereis of item, price ranges to reduce noise for the end user. 
Typically when an item is displayed they show a histogram of price ranges is displayed in ecommerce sites. Are there standard algorithms that these sites use for this display?.

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems to me that you would first and foremost need a way to aggregate this data. That having been said, if you have that data and need to create a histogram it can be fairly simple in the programming language R (here is some documentation: http://www.stat.ucl.ac.be/ISdidactique/Rhelp/library/base/html/hist.html ). There is also an R extension I've read about that allows you to post/run R code in wiki-like pages ( http://mars.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/mediawiki/slides/index.php/R_extension_-_Mediawiki ).

If you already have this data (in this case prices) I dont think you need an algorithm so much as you just need a way to display it in a type of graph. I think R should be useful. I hope this helps!